# Given error message is not displayed in Spring Form validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I want to validate my form fields. I followed [this tutorial](http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/) . I just want to show a my given error message(No need to use MessageResource,but hard coded message inside the pojo). I use Hibernate and spring validation as above tutorial used. This is my pojo which is used as the model attribute with validation annotations.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class User {

    @NotNull(message="username cannot be empty")
    private String username;
    @NotEmpty @Email(message="e mail cannot be empty")
    private String email;
    (... encapsulated getters and setter..)
```

This is my JSP.

```
<form:form action="register" method="post"  commandName="userForm">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2>Spring MVC Form Demo - Registration</h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="username" />
                     <form:errors path="username"></form:errors>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail:</td>
                    <td><form:input path="email" />
                     <form:errors path="email"></form:errors>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration( @ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid   User user
                                        ,BindingResult result
                                        ,Map<String, Object> model) {

         if(result.hasErrors()){
                     return "registration";
         }
return "profile";
```

inside my pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When there is a field error, the page shows only the default error which is `may not be empty`. How can I set my given error message instead of default error? Anyone can see any wrong in my implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your current code you'll get `username cannot be empty` only if username is null. Change it to `@NotEmpty`. And you'll get `e mail cannot be empty` only if the email formatting is incorrect. If email is empty, the default message will be printed because you haven't attached any message to `@NotEmpty` of email property. @Sanjay's suggestion will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this and see whether it works:

```
@NotEmpty(message="username cannot be empty")
private String username;

@NotEmpty(message="email cannot be empty")
@Email(message="email not well formed")
private String email;
```